# The usage of "to look"

Tags: verbs

I just saw this headline "Researchers look a dinosaur in its remarkably preserved face" on arstechnica.

I was wondering if this sentence is correct, or is there a different use of the verb "look" I am not familiar with? thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal meaning of "look" (ie perceive using your eyes), in an idiomatic expression  "look (someone) in the face". The idiom means simply look directly at another person's face (usually so that you can see each other's expression)

> Look me in the face when you speak, and I'll know if you are lying.

The but this is not really the point in the headline.  It is just that there is a dinosaur with a preserved face that the scientists are looking at. The headline writers have just used the idiom because it is a familiar expression with "look" and "face", so is catchy and makes you want to read the article.